# Create web page that allows to browse MSSQL server database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I need to create webpage that should display one table from `MSSQL` server database. I suppose the easiest way is to use `C#`, create some kind of project and add visual components to display table. What kind of project I need to create and which components to use to visualize table?

Comment: What you have described is what C# developers do for ALL project and is quite ambigious. Technology (ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC etc.) and component to use (UI layout) are subject to the developer. There is no certain prescription for such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start Visual Studio
2. Select New Project
3. Choose Visual C#
4. Choose ASP.Net Web App
5. Enter Name at bottom of screen
6. Select Web Forms from Choose Templates Window
7. Click on Default.ASPX in solution explorer window to your right.
8. Delete everything between the tags 
   asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   and /asp:Content

   9. Bring up Solution Explorer. (Ctrl-Alt-S). It usually appears on your left.
9. Under the Data Connections tab create a connection to the SQL Server Instance your are using. Select the database you want to use from the dropdown list of 'Select or enter a database name.'
10. Click on Test Connection to verify that you have connected.
11. In the main window click on the design tab on your bottom left.
12. From the Solution Explorer Window expand the tab Tables/Views to select the table you want to expose to the user.
13. Drag the table to the Design window under the area Main Content (custom).
14. A gui will pop up titled Grid View Tasks. Fill it in so it matches your requirements.
15. Press the f5 function key to see what the web page will look like and how it will behave.
16. Save everything  (Ctrl-Sift-S) and publish the page.
17. Add security at both the Web level and at SQL Server level (you probably want to create a read only view of the data).
18. Learn MVC so you can create a site that is maintainable and extendable.
19. This was done using Visual Studio 2013. Your version of Visual Studio may differ slightly.
20. Visual Studio has generated quite a bit of objects that you may want to customize. You probably want to start at the Sitemaster page. As a beginner I would save my project and after every change, run it, and see if everything is still OK.

Comment: Sharm! How to make this GridView edit data in database?